# Xcode 7.1 crash if you disable Auto Layout on tvOS storyboard - How to fix?

Tags: xcode, crash, storyboard, autolayout, xcode7.1

Xcode 7.1 crash if you disable Auto Layout on tvOS storyboard. 
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by setting the flag manually in the XIB source.  You can do this directly in XCode:

- Right-click the .xib file and choose Open As > Source Code
- Search for "autolayout"
- Change the autolayout YES setting to NO

Comment: That sucks.  It worked out for me fortunately and only changing the setting in the UI made mine crash.